# PM2 save std err and std output in same file

Tags: node.js, logging, pm2

I have a Nodejs script that I'm running using PM2 but it saves stderr and std output in separate files. But I want to know after which output message an error occured. This is only possible if PM2 doesn't separate the std error and std output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-l --log [path]` with the pm2 command

```
pm2 start app -l --log "path to log file"
```

[link](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/) for the more details